# Solr pivot faceting max level

Tags: solr, pivot, facet

I use pivot faceting for hierarchical categories, as described here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HierarchicalFaceting#Pivot_Facets

When there is no category selected, I simply use:

```
facet.field = category_level0
```

When I select a level 0 category, I remove facet.field and add:

```
facet.pivot = category_level0, category_level1
```

Now I can see the level 0 category and all its level 1 subcategories.

When I select a level 1 category, I use:

```
facet.pivot = category_level0, category_level1, category_level2
```

This gives me level 0, 1, and its level 2 subcategories.

The problem is I only have 3 levels: 0, 1 and 2.

So if I add category_level3 to facet.pivot, I get nothing, because level 3 does not exist.

This might be a long shot, but is there any parameter which can tell solr to consider a pivot value only if it exists in the results?

Answer (score 0):

You can set facet.missing=true. This will (or should) calculate the values even if facets values are missing.